# Maven, testng, surefire: not running AfterClass

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there a reason why maven would not run my AfterClass which is set to alwaysRun=true? BeforeClass is run without issues and test passes according to surefire report. I run command in terminal:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestSuite2#test_case3 test
```

and get

```
Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:10.228s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 13 18:24:07 EET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is though that my AfterClass, where I quit driver (driver.quit()) is not run. Everything works as expected, if I run the same test via Eclipse with TestNG (right click on the method, run as TestNG test)

Comment: Currently I can only solve this by changing AfterClass to AfterSuite

Comment: Can you please show your class structure, with method names and annotations?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, with AfterSuite methods too. I have a BaseTestCase with my before and after suite methods, which is then extended by each of my test classes. The AfterSuite annotations are set to alwaysRun=true, but I'm not seeing my clean up occurring..

Comment: you can try it with AfterTest and BeforeTest instead of AfterClass and BeforeClss.

Answer (score 0):

It works in IDE (Eclipse/IDEA) because it creates testng.xml and run test against it. You need to check pom.xml and revise your [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) configuration.